# How to evaluate a matched number later in a regex? - Lexing FORTRAN 'H' edit descriptor with Ply

Tags: python, regex, lexical-analysis, ply

I am using [Ply](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) to interpret a FORTRAN format string. I am having trouble writing a regex to match the ['H' edit descriptor](http://www.fortran.com/F77_std/rjcnf0001-sh-13.html#sh-13.5.2) which is of the form

*x*H*ccccc ...*

where *x* specifies the number of characters to read in after the 'H'

Ply matches tokens with a single regular expression, but I am having trouble using regular expression to perform the above. I am looking for something like,

`(\d+)[Hh].{\1}`

where `\1` is parsed as an integer and evaluated as part of the regex - however it isn't.

It seems that [it is not possible to use matched numbers later in the same regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646316/do-calculation-on-captured-number-in-regex-before-using-it-in-replacement), is this the case?

Does anyone have any other solutions that might use Ply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex can't do things like that. You can hack it though:

```
(1[Hh].|2[Hh]..|3[Hh]...|etc...)
```

Ugly!

Comment: Crude and limited, but effective. Good idea for a one off.

Answer (score 0):

This is what comes of thinking that regexps can replace a lexer.

Short version: regular expressions can only deal with that small subset of all possible language termed "regular" (big surprise, I know). But "regular" is not isomorphic to the human understanding of "simple", so even very simple languages can have non-regular expressions.

Writing a lexer for a simple language is not terribly hard.

That canonical Stack Overflow question for resources on the topic is [Learning to write a compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler).

---

Ah. I seem to have misunderstood the question. Mea Culpa.

I'm not familiar with ply, and its been a while since I used flex, but think you would eat *any number of* following digits, then *check* in the associated code block if the rules had been obeyed.

Comment: Ply is a Python library that implements lex and yacc style rules within Python for creating a Lexer/Parser. I was under the impression that using lex/yacc will save me a lot of tedious coding when writing parsers

Answer (score 0):

Pyparsing includes an adaptive expression that is very similar to this, called countedArray.  countedArray(expr) parses a leading integer 'n' and then parses 'n' instances of expr, returning the whole array as a single list.  The way this works is that countedArray parses a leading integer expression, followed by an uninitialized Forward expression.  The leading integer expression has a parse action attached that assigns the following Forward to 'n'*expr.  The pyparsing parser then continues on, and parses the following 'n' expr's.  So it is sort of a self-modifying parser.

To parse your expression, this would look something like:

```
integer = Word(nums).setParseAction(lambda t:int(t[0]))
following = Forward()
integer.addParseAction(lambda t: following << Word(printables+" ",exact=t[0]))
H_expr = integer + 'H' + following
print H_expr.parseString("22HThis is a test string.This is not in the string")
```

Prints:

```
[22, 'H', 'This is a test string.']
```

If Ply has something similar, perhaps you could use this technique.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful to know. I had considered Pyparsing earlier but decided to go with the more UNIX'ey old school lex/yacc Ply way - and now the parser is all but written save this last detail!